# How do you know where the inkwell is tapped in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have an app that should have a different functionality if the user double taps on the right side of the `InkWell` and on the left side of the `InkWell`, but I don't see any way of doing that, so could someone help me do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable with [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html). Instead you can use [Listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html), a lower layer, to detect where the pointed landed.